# Displaying the currently loaded data while reading data from a table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a SQL Server table that has approximately 2 million rows. Let's say the table is called `Students`. If I query a database from SQL Server Management Studio:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Students
```

At the same time, the currently loaded data is displayed, and the rest of it is being loaded in the meantime. By this I mean, for example after 1 second I see 1000 lines, after 2 seconds I see 3000 lines and so on ....

However, if I use EF in my application and I query the database for the data:

```
var data = _context.Students.ToList();
```

I have to wait for all the rows of the table to load before I can access the `data` object.I know that theoretically I could use pagination and retrieve only part of the records (for example, from 1 - 100).

But is there any mechanism / library in the ASP.NET Core application that would allow me to display a table on the page and load the rows on the fly?

Comment: Do you really want to show 2 millions records to your end users?

Comment: Don't use `ToList`, just feed the repository straight into your DataGrid (or whatever), then it will feed them through as they come. Although how you expect a user to view 2million records is a different question, most answers to this type of problem are not to do it in the first place.

Comment: I partially agree with @Charlieface but it's not going to make any difference because it will bind data only when all the records are available. Better way to use paging or some event like scroll to load next records. Here is an [example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/custom-paging-with-gridview-control-in-Asp-Net-4-5/) .

Comment: @शेखर Presumably whatever is being used currently is able to page it. OP has not specified what binding is being used. Agreed paging or querying should be used anyway

Comment: @Steve Let's say this was an example. A few months ago, I talked to a developer who had to implement about a million rows in a table at a time (including data from about 10 different tables bound by foreign keys). That's where I saw that data was displayed and loaded simultaneously. Unfortunately, I never learned from him how he implemented it: /

Comment: Keep in mind that any streaming solution is not scalable at all. The best you can do is a continuous scroll pattern.

Comment: There is also the memory problem. Whatever user interface gizmo is tasked with the display of two millions of records will probably consume a lot of memory and will stop to display anything well before reaching the end of the stream. So some kind of _pagination_ is mandatory at the UI level even in case of continuous loading

Comment: Please consider the way the end user will use the system, I can't imagine many users will be happy to wait for these to load, maybe give them a search option to narrow down the number of rows returned. A user is not going to scroll through 100's of pages.

Comment: Pagination should be good enough, but there are also "lazy loading" techniques.  For instance, your controller could look up one record at a time, and javascript would populate the DOM per record...  (JS can use a simple loop or even async requests to the server... you can also prioritize on-screen elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But is there any mechanism / library in the ASP.NET Core application that would allow me to display a table on the page and load the rows on the fly?

In a web app the most common pattern is to return data one page at-a-time.  Any time the user hits [Next] or scrolls down on the table, the next page of data is fetched.  This is called Paging (like Stack Overflow) or Virtual Scrolling (like Facebook).

See eg [Tutorial: Add sorting, filtering, and paging - ASP.NET MVC with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Answer (score 0):

This is very common problem for developers...ha ha

Every on has a different way to handle that. I would like to suggest 2 ways.

1. You can handle that by SQL Server in stored procedure using count from to
2. You can handle that by pagination on paging number call run time data on number click